# How can I set the part name and title on the same line?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lyx, parts

How can I set part name and title on the same line. Now (at default) , the Part number is at one line, and the name of part is one line below... For example, instead of

> **PART I
>
>   This is my title**

I want

> **PART I   This is my title**

Here is a simple code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\part{why this line is one line down?}

How can I make the the name of part one will be at the same line at
the PDF output.
\end{document}
```

---

Edit: Here is my document preamble:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\R{\textbf{הוכחה:}}}%
{\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}\par\vspace{2mm}}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{\R{טענה}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{bbding}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\makeatletter
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
\makeatother
} % end of \xyR
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyC}[1]{%
\makeatletter
\xydef@\xymatrixcolsep@{#1}
\makeatother
} % end of \xyC
\def\thepart{\alph{part}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\par}{\quad}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\Large}{\huge}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
```

When I adding the code above to this, it's doesn't work...

---

Here is my document preamble:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\R{\textbf{הוכחה:}}}%
{\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}\par\vspace{2mm}}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{\R{טענה}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{bbding}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\makeatletter
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
\makeatother
} % end of \xyR
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyC}[1]{%
\makeatletter
\xydef@\xymatrixcolsep@{#1}
\makeatother
} % end of \xyC
\def\thepart{\alph{part}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\par}{\quad}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\Large}{\huge}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
```

When I adding the code above to this, it's doesn't work...

Comment: Care to explain a bit more? Some code that demonstrates your problem? I don't understand your question. For instance, what do you mean by "part"?

Comment: I posted a simple code..:-)

Comment: Load package `babel` earlier. Option `hebrew` loads `rlbabel.def` that overwrites `\@part`. The patch of [werner's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124278/16967) also works for `\@part` of `rlbabel.def`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition that drives the display of `\part` is actually `\@part`:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
```

The part name and number is set in `\Large\bfseries`, followed by `\par`. You can remove this `\par`agraph break using a patch from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) by adding the following to your document preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\par}{\quad}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The above patch replaces `\par` with `\quad` (a `1em` space):

[image]

Doesn't look pretty... perhaps you can update the part name/number to math the font of the part title through another preamble addition:

```
\renewcommand{\partname}{\huge Part}
```

[image]

A similar output is obtained by adding the following patch with the previous one:

```
\patchcmd{\@part}{\Large}{\huge}{}{}
```

Comment: Thank you! it should work at Hebrew articles? I to do this on my Hebrew article ant it's doesn't work :-(

Comment: @YoavFridman: I guess your "simple code" was just too simple. Update your question with the necessary details and a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem. That way I (and the community) know *exactly* what you're dealing with. It just saves time, honestly.

Comment: @YoavFridman: For language-specific changes to structural units in your document, see [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://goo.gl/CQdc6)

Comment: This dosen't work at Arabic document in Polyglossia package.