# Fixing part layout using \patchcmd

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, koma-script, etoolbox

I want to remove the linebreak between part numeration and part name as found  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/how-can-i-set-the-part-name-and-title-on-the-same-line). However the solution doesn't work for me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft, onecolumn, oneside, paper=a4, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@part}{\par}{\quad}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \part{A}
\end{document}
```

"Part I." and "A" are still displayed in seperate lines. The output doesn't containg error warnings.

I'm using overleaf and pdfLaTeX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `\patchcmd{\@part}{\par}{\quad}{}{\PatchFailed}` you would get the error message that `\PatchFailed` is not defined. Then you would know that the false part of `\patchcmd` is excecuted because the patch fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid patching internal KOMA-Script commands. Redefine the KOMA-Script command `\partheadmidvskip` to remove the linebreak between the part number and the part text:

```
\renewcommand*\partheadmidvskip{\enskip}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*\partheadmidvskip{\enskip}
\begin{document}
\part{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer helps, you can upvote it and if it solves the issue, you can accept it.

Comment: @Jonathan If you like this answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. That is the preferred way to say thank you on this site.